# IIS SSL Problems During Heavy Server Use

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

My IIS web server farm (Windows 2008 R2) is experiencing heavy server use and SSL requests are timing out on what appears to be the TLS negotiation (500+ Get Requests/sec with over 20K Current Connections).

Despite the heavy load, the performance of the servers are fine--less than 20% processor utilization, 75% of memory still available, and virtually no processor queuing. Additionally, the bandwidth utilization was fine as well. However, during this event, my websites stopped responding to SSL-based (https) requests and clients were unable to negotiate a TLS connection. During this same time, requests using http were working fine and the websites were very responsive (I disabled the IIS rewrite rule from http to https).

In troubleshooting, the only thing I see is that my Windows event logs are filled with Event ID: 36887, which seems to be related to SSL but the meaning of the error is vague to me. There are hundreds of entries per minute corresponding to the time of the performance issues. This is description I find for the error:

*This error message indicates the computer received an SSL fatal alert message from the server ( It is not a bug in the Schannel or the application that uses Schannel). Sometimes is caused by the installation of third party web browser (other than Internet Explorer).*

Does this mean that my server was unable to communicate with the CA server? What would cause this problem with TLS unable to negotiate a connection under a heavy load?

Comment: I hope someone has some ideas, but if not... You are down to your last four months of [supported life](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4456235/end-of-support-for-windows-server-2008-and-windows-server-2008-r2) for Windows Server 2008 R2. Because you are going to have to replace that server anyway, it probably makes sense to replace it now, and the problem will likely go away, either through improvements to the OS, or improvements to IIS, or through the process of a clean configuration removing some leftover cruft.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely a wake-up call to migrate our web server infrastructure sooner rather than later. However, nobody seems to have an explanation at all as to what the cause might be.